# Upload a file using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a problem trying to upload a file into an API. In the swagger UI I have not problem uploading an excel file manually. When I try tu upload using request, I recive a 415 error (Invalid format of my file). Here is a simple code of that post request:

```
 headers = {
        'Authorization':"bearer "+ CLIENT.token,
        'Content-Type': 'form-data' 
           }
 files = [('file', open(path_to_file, 'rb'))]

 response = requests.post(api_url,  
    files=files,
    headers=headers)
```

My response has status code 415, I dont Know what is happening. When I used the swagger, I inspected the newtwork browser, and I saw this header in the request

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarywkrdGd3ROh0GkfsW
```

But, I don't know what is the term "boundary", and if I pass this header manually into the requests, the API throws a 500.

Comment: what is real url ? Do you have documentation for this API ? Maybe it needs something more. You can send it to `http://httpbin.org/post` in swagger UI and requests and you get information what did you send and then you can compare there information.

Answer (score 1):

The server is saying that your `Content-Type` is wrong. If you're uploading a `.xls` file use:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
```

If you're uploading a `.xlsx` file use:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but even doing I get the 415 status

Comment: @Andrex Try `application/octet-stream`